# Htaccess mod rewrite help

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to redirect the url:

http://www.mysite.com/invite/YhMck/en

to

http://www.mysite.com/auth/accept_invite/YhMck/en

can any please help me with the RewiteRule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your `.htaccess` in your `documentroot`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/invite
RewriteRule ^invite/([^/]+)/(\w{2})$ auth/accept_invite/$1/$2
```

from comments:
These rules:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|images|img|css|js|fonts) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Will add index.php to every rule that does not begin with `index.php|robots\.txt|images|img|css|js|fonts`

So your `/invite` would also have been re-written to `/index.php/invite...`

---

Try this in the same order

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/invite
RewriteRule ^invite/([^/]+)/(\w{2})$ auth/accept_invite/$1/$2 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(auth/|index\.php|robots\.txt|images|img|css|js|fonts) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: 1>

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/invite

RewriteRule ^/invite/([\w\-]*)/([\w\-]*)$ /index.php/auth/accept_invitation/$1/$2

1.1>(since I am already using this to do away with index.php)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/invite

RewriteRule ^/invite/([\w\-]*)/([\w\-]*)$ /auth/accept_invitation/$1/$2

2>

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([\w\-.\/:]*)\/invite\/([\w\-]*)\/([\w\-]*)$

RewriteRule ^([\w\-.\/:]*)\/invite\/([\w\-]*)\/([\w\-]*)$ $1/index.php/auth/accept_invitation/$2/$3

Comment: @SNAG Are you on shared host?and is mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: not on a shared host and mod rewrite is enabled. I am already using that to get rid of index.php

Comment: @SNAG post the rewrite rules you are using to get rid of `index.php`. Post it in the question. Its very difficult to read it in comments.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|images|img|css|js|fonts)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: yes it worked and since I am using codeigniter I could have used its routing function. feel silly now. anyway thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com/invite/YhMck/en
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/auth/accept_invite/YhMck/en/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On

Comment: the "YhMck/en" part will vary are parameters and will vary. so can I use * for them?